# jQuery qTip not changing classes ?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, qtip

Hii i am using qTip 2 i want the class `ui-tooltip-dark ui-tooltip-shadow` but it doesnt shows that class. I have this code:

```
    $('.selector').qtip({
   content: {
      text: function(api) {
         // Retrieve content from custom attribute of the $('.selector') elements.
         return $(this).attr('qtip-content');
        }
      },
      title: {
         text: function(api) {
            // Retrieve content from ALT attribute of the $('.selector') element
            return $(this).attr('alt');
         }
      },
     style: {
      classes: 'ui-tooltip-dark ui-tooltip-shadow';
      }
});
```

But when i put the code that is on their site it works

Can u please tell me where am i going wrong ?

**EDIT**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" class="example">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.selector').qtip({
   content: {
      text: function(api) {
         // Retrieve content from custom attribute of the $('.selector') elements.
         return $(this).attr('qtip-content');
      }
     },
      title: {
         text: function(api) {
            // Retrieve content from ALT attribute of the $('.selector') element
            return $(this).attr('alt');
         }
      },
     style: {
      classes: 'ui-tooltip-dark ui-tooltip-shadow';
      }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please post the code from the demo site that you say is working.   And if the code from the demo is working for you, just use that?

Comment: I modified it , to get this but it diesnt works

Comment: This is the last time I'm going to ask this:  **Please post the code that was working for you**.  You said, _"when i put the code that is on their site it works"_.  So just show us what "works" **just before** you modified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might just be a typo in what you've posted but you're missing a curly brace around the content section -

```
$('.selector').qtip({
   content: {
      text: function(api) {
         // Retrieve content from custom attribute of the $('.selector') elements.
         return $(this).attr('qtip-content');
      }
     },
      title: {
         text: function(api) {
            // Retrieve content from ALT attribute of the $('.selector') element
            return $(this).attr('alt');
         }
      },
     style: {
      classes: 'ui-tooltip-dark ui-tooltip-shadow';
      }
});
```

**EDIT**

Try this -

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.selector').qtip({
   content: {
      text: function(api) {
         // Retrieve content from custom attribute of the $('.selector') elements.
         return $(this).attr('qtip-content');
      },
      title: {
         text: function(api) {
            // Retrieve content from ALT attribute of the $('.selector') element
            return $(this).attr('alt');
         }
      }
   },
   style: {
      classes: 'ui-tooltip-dark ui-tooltip-shadow'
      }      
    });
});
```

You should be able to see it working here - http://jsfiddle.net/KaJ9q/

Comment: Could you post a link to the code on the qtip web site that you say works?

Comment: Btw the js console says : 
[21:22:28.741] missing } after property list @ http://localhost/Apply/:109

Comment: Thanks, could you post your html?

Comment: its too big around 150 lines , but the 109th line is the line where the <script> starts

Comment: Oopsi can i tell u tommorow cus i dont have my system now sorry :(

Comment: @ipr101:  Looking at your edited answer... please explain what you did to fix it.

Comment: @Sparky673: The main change was nesting the title element inside the content element. I hadn't realised initially that that was the way it was supposed to work.

Comment: Yes LOL it worked.
It is 3:00 AM here i got up to see if it does work AND IT DID WOOO.
If it wouldnt have had i was coming to kill you
Thanks A lot :D :D: D